# Aligning ends of toolbar with ends of table in Bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap3, I have a "toolbar" above a table. The toolbar has a series of input fields and buttons. I need the left/right ends of the toolbar to align with the ends of the table.

I tried to use Bootstrap's column classes to position the various toolbar elements. The positioning seems to be correct when viewed in full screen mode on a typical large (or greater) display.

I am able to align the fields and buttons to the end of the table if I remove the left and right padding from the first and last `div`s respectively. This is what I'm currently doing and it works. But I was hoping to achieve this without overriding the default styles. I suspect there is a simpler way of doing this that I am missing.

This is a little different than I'm used to since there are several different types of elements in the toolbar.

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="btn-toolbar">
         <div class="col-sm-2">
           <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
             <div>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" />
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-2">
           <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
             <div>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" />
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-2">
           <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
           <div>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
               Get Data
             </button>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-2">
           <div class="form-group">
             <div>
               <label class="control-label">Search</label>
               <input type="search" class="form-control" />
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-1">
           <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
           <div>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
               Search
             </button>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
           <div class="pull-right">
             <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
             <div class="btn-toolbar">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Create
               </button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                 Close
               </button>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
           <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>Col1</th>
               <th>Col2</th>
               <th>Col3</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             <tr>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>2</td>
               <td>3</td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two elements are extra in your code. One of them is the `.btn-toolbar` (the one in between `.row` and Bootstrap grid columns) while the second is `.row` around the `table` element.

Wrapping `.row` around the table is excess because you are not using any columns inside this row. Further remove `.btn-toolbar` element as well because you have set some custom `margin-left` here which is causing some misalignment from the left side.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
          <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
          <div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Get Data</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div>
            <label class="control-label">Search</label>
            <input type="search" class="form-control" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
        <div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="pull-right">
          <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
          <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col1</th>
          <th>Col2</th>
          <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thank you!